AAPT: error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar not found
I know there are a number of posts on this but I have tried the tips in all of them and have been banging my head agains this for days now!
I am using Android Studio Koala 2024.1.1.
Part of build.gradle is below.
Part of my manifest is below.
My themes are below.
Despite:
Enabling androidx AND
Trying all the mentioned dependencies in various posts, AND
Being careful to reference themes correctly (and tried @style/ and no @style/ at start of referce) AND
Invalidate cache and restart AND
Clean project
Whenever I try to
Build -> Rebuild Project Or
Build -> Generate Signed APK
I get
ERROR: AAPT: error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar (aka org.gearlog.app:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar) not found.
error: failed linking references.
Supporting info:
build.gradle (app) dependencies (I know this is too many - just showing all that I have tried!):
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.68.2"  
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.7.0"

}

AndroidManifest part:
 <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity 
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"

Themes
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/app_bg</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/app_bg</item>
        <item name="android:editTextBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>


    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/splashscreen_bg</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
    </style>

If anyone could help I would be SO grateful!

Other info that maybe useful: The App can be run in emulator fine with 'react-native run-android' from CLI and also by hitting the AVD 'Play' Icon in the Studio (why does that work fine when build fails?? Surely the Theme is needed either way and seems to be found OK when deployed to an emulator). I have also tried (from various other posts): (a) Close the project and reopen (b) delete .idea and .gradle and re-ope (c) Delete build-cache and run sych (d) delete project libraries and re-synch (e) Comment out the support depends, clean and un-comment). Same error whatever I do!
